# Trying to Populate TableView from JSON file in Chat App?

Tags: ios, json, uitableview

I am working with a chat app template, which I have already integrated into my main app. I wish each row of the table to display data from a json file, so that the chat room name and details of the room are displayed to the user, but can be changed at my wish without having to resubmit the app to apple each time.

Instead of putting the full code here, it's really long, so I put it [Here](http://www.mackuk.co.uk/MenuViewController.m) EDIT: It's also below now.

Additionally, instead of deleting the original code (because the room names for example were already designated within the app), I have scored it out so you're not guessing which changes I have made from the original template.

Finally, my problem… When I run the app the data appears how I want it from the JSON File within the tableview, however when a row is selected the app crashes instead of taking the user through to the chat room.

I'm in above my head in terms of figuring this out and I've tried searching on here and google with each term I can think of to solve it.

The error messaage I get in the console is:

**2014-08-13 09:27:23.708 Huddle[6073:60b] -[__NSCFDictionary stringByTrimmingCharactersInSet:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x17e85350**

I wanted to post a screenshot, but this won't allow me - so uploaded it to my web server instead - [Here](http://mackuk.co.uk/screenshot.tiff) (if this is not allowed, please don't put this question on hold again, just email me & I'll remove the link to the image straight away, I'm just trying to provide all the info I can).

Thanks a million for any help in advance!

EDIT: Admins of site require the full code in this question, so edited to add:

```
    #import "ProgressHUD.h"
    #import <Firebase/Firebase.h>
    #import <FirebaseSimpleLogin/FirebaseSimpleLogin.h>

    #import "common.h"
    #import "utilities.h"

    #import "MenuViewController.h"
    #import "LoginViewController.h"
    #import "ChatViewController.h"


    @interface MenuViewController()
    {
NSDictionary *userinfo;
NSMutableArray *items;
NSURL *url;


UIBarButtonItem *buttonLogin;
UIBarButtonItem *buttonLogout;
    }
    @end


    @implementation MenuViewController


    - (void)viewDidLoad

    {


[super viewDidLoad];
self.title = @"Chat";

userinfo = nil;

// Allocate Memory for the raw JSON Dictionary, and for just the tv episodes.
userinfo = [[NSDictionary alloc] init];
items = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];

// Setup the URL with the JSON URL.
url = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://mackuk.co.uk/chat.json"];

[self parseJSONWithURL:url];

/*ORIGINAL CHAT ROOM NAMES

 items = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
[items addObject:@"Room 1"];
[items addObject:@"Room 2"];
*/

buttonLogin = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithTitle:@"Login" style:UIBarButtonItemStyleBordered target:self action:@selector(actionLogin)];
buttonLogout = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithTitle:@"Logout" style:UIBarButtonItemStyleBordered target:self action:@selector(actionLogout)];

[self checkAuthStatus];



    }

    - (void) parseJSONWithURL:(NSURL *) jsonURL
    {
        // Set the queue to the background queue. We will run this on the background thread to keep
// the UI Responsive.
dispatch_queue_t queue = dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_BACKGROUND, 0);

[UIApplication sharedApplication].networkActivityIndicatorVisible = YES;

// Run request on background queue (thread).
dispatch_async(queue, ^{
    NSError *error = nil;

    // Request the data and store in a string.
    NSString *json = [NSString stringWithContentsOfURL:jsonURL
                                              encoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding
                                                 error:&error];
    if (error == nil){

        // Convert the String into an NSData object.
        NSData *jsonData = [json dataUsingEncoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding];

        // Parse that data object using NSJSONSerialization without options.
        userinfo = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:jsonData options:kNilOptions error:&error];

        // Parsing success.
        if (error == nil)
        {
            dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
                [UIApplication sharedApplication].networkActivityIndicatorVisible = NO;
                items = [[userinfo valueForKey:@"Chat"] valueForKey:@"rooms"];
                [self.tableView reloadData];
            });
        }

        // Parsing failed, display error as alert.
        else
        {
            UIAlertView *alertView = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Error!" message:@"Uh Oh, Parsing Failed." delegate:nil cancelButtonTitle:@"Dismiss" otherButtonTitles:nil];

            [alertView show];
        }
    }

    // Request Failed, display error as alert.
    else
    {
        UIAlertView *alertView = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Error!" message:@"Request Error! Check that you are connected to wifi or 3G/4G with internet access." delegate:nil cancelButtonTitle:@"Dismiss" otherButtonTitles:nil];

        [alertView show];
    }
});
    }


    - (void)showError:(id)message

    {
[ProgressHUD showError:message Interacton:NO];
    }


    - (void)checkAuthStatus

    {
[ProgressHUD show:@"Please wait..." Interacton:NO];

Firebase *ref = [[Firebase alloc] initWithUrl:FIREBASE];
FirebaseSimpleLogin *authClient = [[FirebaseSimpleLogin alloc] initWithRef:ref];
[authClient checkAuthStatusWithBlock:^(NSError *error, FAUser *user)
{
    if (error == nil)
    {
        [ProgressHUD dismiss];

        if (user != nil)
        {
            userinfo = ParseUserData(user.thirdPartyUserData);
            self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = buttonLogout;
        }
        else self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = buttonLogin;
    }
    else
    {
        NSString *message = [error.userInfo valueForKey:@"NSLocalizedDescription"];
        [self performSelectorOnMainThread:@selector(showError:) withObject:message waitUntilDone:NO];
    }
}];
    }


    - (void)actionLogin

    {
LoginViewController *loginViewController = [[LoginViewController alloc] init];
loginViewController.delegate = self;

UINavigationController *navController = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:loginViewController];
navController.navigationBar.translucent = NO;
navController.navigationBar.barTintColor = COLOR_TITLE;
navController.navigationBar.tintColor = COLOR_TITLETEXT;
navController.navigationBar.titleTextAttributes = @{NSForegroundColorAttributeName:COLOR_TITLETEXT};
[self presentViewController:navController animated:YES completion:nil];
    }


    - (void)didFinishLogin:(NSDictionary *)Userinfo

    {
userinfo = [Userinfo copy];
self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = buttonLogout;
    }


    - (void)actionLogout

    {
Firebase *ref = [[Firebase alloc] initWithUrl:FIREBASE];
FirebaseSimpleLogin *authClient = [[FirebaseSimpleLogin alloc] initWithRef:ref];
[authClient logout];

userinfo = nil;
self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = buttonLogin;
    }

    #pragma mark - Table view data source


    - (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView

    {
return 1;
    }

    - (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section

    {

return [items count];
    }


    - (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath

    {

UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"cell"];

if (cell == nil)
{
    cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleSubtitle reuseIdentifier:@"cell"];
}
cell.textLabel.text = [[items objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] objectForKey:@"name"];
NSNumber *seasonNum = [[items objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] objectForKey:@"detail"];
NSNumber *episodeNum = [[items objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] objectForKey:@"kotime"];
NSMutableString *seasonEpisodeNum = [NSMutableString stringWithFormat:@" %@ ", seasonNum];
[seasonEpisodeNum appendString:[NSMutableString stringWithFormat:@" %@", episodeNum]];
cell.detailTextLabel.text = seasonEpisodeNum;

return cell;




/* ORIGINAL CELL INFO

 UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"cell"];
if (cell == nil) cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleSubtitle reuseIdentifier:@"cell"];

cell.textLabel.text = [items objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];



return cell;*/
    }

    #pragma mark - Table view delegate


    - (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath

    {
[tableView deselectRowAtIndexPath:indexPath animated:YES];

if (userinfo != nil)
{
    NSString *chatroom = [items objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    ChatViewController *chatViewController = [[ChatViewController alloc] initWith:chatroom Userinfo:userinfo];
    self.hidesBottomBarWhenPushed = YES;
    [self.navigationController pushViewController:chatViewController animated:YES];
    self.hidesBottomBarWhenPushed=NO;
}
else [self actionLogin];
    }

    #pragma mark iAd Delegate Methods


    -(void)bannerViewDidLoadAd:(ADBannerView *)banner {

[UIView beginAnimations:nil context:nil];
[UIView setAnimationDuration:1];
[banner setAlpha:1];
[UIView commitAnimations];

    }

    -(void)bannerView:(ADBannerView *)banner didFailToReceiveAdWithError:(NSError *)error {

[UIView beginAnimations:nil context:nil];
[UIView setAnimationDuration:1];
[banner setAlpha:0];
[UIView commitAnimations];

    }

    @end
```

Comment: What is the error when it crashes?

Comment: Can you paste the error so we can see what's wrong?

Comment: Post the full and exact error message and post the relevant code causing the error.

Comment: How do I get this question taken off "hold" so that people can answer it now that I have edited the original question?